# Angular Ag-Grid Row Group hide lowest nodes/children

Tags: angular5, ag-grid

is there a way to hide/prevent ag-grid from displaying the lowest level nodes in a row group?

From:
[image]

To:
[image]

Comment: related discussion - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/139

Comment: Doesn't look like they've added the feature.